# YTD Month Start and End Dates based on the Service Date Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I need to create **Month Start Date** and **Month End Date** columns based on the Service Date column.

If Service Date is current month, then Month End date should be Today's Date.

For example:

If Service date was '2022-02-14', then Month Start and Month End dates associated with the date are '2022-01-01' and '2022-02-28'.

However, if Service Date is '2022-04-07' (Current Month), then Month Start and Month End dates associated with the date should be '2022-04-01' and '2022-04-11' (**Today's Date**).

Regular Start and End Dates of the Month:

```
CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @ServiceDate), 0) AS DATE) AS [Month Start Date],
CAST(EOMONTH(@ServiceDate) AS DATE) AS [Month End Date],
```

Comment: use [case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the first of the month logic figured out. For the end of the month, try a case to return today's date if it's the current month. Otherwise, return the last day in the @ServiceDate month

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @ServiceDate), 0) AS DATE) AS [Month Start Date]
      , CASE WHEN dateDiff(month, @ServiceDate, getDate()) = 0 THEN CAST(getDate() AS DATE) 
             ELSE CAST(EOMONTH(@ServiceDate) AS DATE) 
        END AS [Month End Date]
```